# Knockout JS Checked binding depending on selected option

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have to check/uncheck a checkbox on page load depending upon the value from database.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind = "checked: selectedUser() ? selectedUser().user_management : ''"> User Management
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind = "checked: selectedUser() ? selectedUser().client_information : ''"> Client Information
    </label>
</div>
```

Json returned by server is:

```
[{"user_name":"test1","user_management":"1", "client_management":"0"}]
```

Response is used to create following options:

```
<select class="form-control" name="form-edit-user-name" id="form-edit-user-name" data-bind = "options: availableUsers,
                       optionsText: 'user_name',
                       value: selectedUser,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
                            </select>
```

In an ideal scenario user management check box should be checked because it's value in Json is 1 while the client management should not be checked because it's 0. Instead it's checking both the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why your both checkboxes getting checked is (from docs)

> If you give a value that isn’t actually boolean, it will be
>   interpreted loosely. This means that nonzero numbers and non-null
>   objects and non-empty strings will all be interpreted as true, whereas
>   zero, null, undefined, and empty strings will be interpreted as false.

Easy one would be , make `1's & 0's` as boolean or int values not as string from server .

**code:**

```
var json = [{"user_name":"test1","user_management":1, "client_management":0},           {"user_name":"test2","user_management":0, "client_management":1}];
var ViewModel = function() {
var self=this;
    self.availableUsers = ko.observableArray(json);
    self.selectedUser= ko.observable();
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working **[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/29153/)**

Just in case if you want to persist with strings you can tweak you code like **[sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/29156/)**

Comment: Assuming that my server script can't return a boolean but only a string as "1" how can i make this work ?

Comment: @Saurabh please check edit , i added for your scenario . cheers

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks